# "test".partition("s") calls partition from Enumerable module instead of String module

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

I have tried to partition a string using the [partition method from the String module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001215). However, when doing so:

```
puts "test".partition("s")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Line 1:in `partition': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError) from t.rb:1
```

I believe that Ruby calls the [partition method from the Enumerable module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001496), instead of the one from the String module as I wanted.

How can I get Ruby to call the desired method?

Comment: Which version/platform of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Can you put the output of the following in irb:
>> RUBY_VERSION
>> "test".partition("s")

If you're using Ruby 1.8.6, String#partition doesn't do what you think

Comment: I use ruby 1.8.4 (2005-12-24) [i686-linux]

Comment: @Jan that's why it's not working, you're viewing documentation for 1.8.7 or 1.9.2. You're using an ancient version of Ruby. I recommend upgrading to either 1.8.7 or 1.9.2

Comment: irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.4"
irb(main):002:0> "test".partition("s")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
        from (irb):2:in `partition'
        from (irb):2

Comment: I once came across a similar issue in Rubinius: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/1005

Comment: I tripped over this problem (reading the wrong docs) recently in Regex#match and String#match, which take an optional second parameter (offset) in 1.9.3. The search was compounded by my text editor starting rspec with ruby 1.8.7, while my tests in irb were using 1.9.3. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [injekt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310892/injekt) has pointed out, 1.8.4 is too old. [APIdock](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/partition) shows that String#partition only appears in 1.8.7. Upgrade.